# Sending a text file from Java server to C client

Tags: java, c, client-server

I am trying to send a text file from a Java server to a C client. After I ran my code, the text file was received successfully but when i opened it, i found out that some random data had been inserted in the text file.

This is the server code for sending the file.

```
public void sendFile(Socket socket, String file) throws IOException 
{
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];

    while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer);
    }

    fis.close();
    dos.close();    
}
```

And this is the client code  for receiving the file.

```
int recv_file(int sock, char* file_name)
{
     char send_str [MAX_SEND_BUF]; 
     int fp; 
     int sent_bytes, rcvd_bytes, rcvd_file_size;
     int recv_count; 
     unsigned int recv_str[MAX_RECV_BUF];
     size_t send_strlen; 
     send_strlen = strlen(send_str); 
     if ( (fp = open(file_name, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0 )
     {
           perror("error creating file");
           return -1;
     }
     recv_count = 0;
     rcvd_file_size = 0;
     while ( (rcvd_bytes = recv(sock, recv_str, MAX_RECV_BUF/*256*/, 0)) > 0 )
     {
           recv_count++;
           rcvd_file_size += rcvd_bytes;
           if (write(fp, recv_str, rcvd_bytes) < 0 )
           {
                  perror("error writing to file");
                  return -1;
           }
           printf("%dThe data received is %u\n", ++count, recv_str);
     }
     close(fp);
     printf("Client Received: %d bytes in %d recv(s)\n", rcvd_file_size,    recv_count);
     return rcvd_file_size;
}
```

And this is the text file received at the client side.
[Received text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFwLf.png)

This gibberish is added to the text file, how do i resolve this issue?

Comment: In Java it seems you write more than you read. Check in Java how much data you read and only write that part to your DOS.

Comment: You don't want/need a `DataOutputStream`! Use the plain output stream of the socket!

Comment: @JimmyB It doesn't make any difference whether he uses a `DataOutputStream` or the output stream of the socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a `DataOutputStream` because it provides no benefit here. Just use the plain `OutputStream` from the socket.

Then, you must make sure you only write as much data as there is in the file.

So instead of

```
while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
    dos.write(buffer);
}
```

use

```
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
int len;
while ( (len = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    os.write(buffer,0,len);
}
```

to make sure you only write as many bytes as there are in the file.

Comment: `DataOutputStream` is certainly *redundant* here, as none of its specific methods is being called, but it does *not* 'encode the data you write'. The only problem here was in the copy loop.

Comment: @EJB You're right. I was thinking about `ObjectOutputStream`. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: @JimmyB Well `ObjectOutputStream.write()` doesn't encode either, but it does add a stream header.

Comment: @EJP Yes, it does prepend type information to every object written, which correlated with the OP's statement that "data had been _inserted_ in the text file" and led me to erroneously think of ObjectOutputStream.

Answer (score 2):

```
while (fis.read(buffer) > 0) {
    dos.write(buffer);
}
```

Your copy loop is incorrect. You are writing junk at the end of the file, if not before. It should be:

```
int count;
while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    dos.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: yes, the code was adding junk at the end of the file, the counter variable solved the problem.